# GXT Page grid is not displaying data

Tags: gwt, grid, gxt

Migrated to GXt 3.1.4 /GWT 2.7.0,

But data in the paging grid is not displaying info, Paging bar is working fine but not data in UI.

Any possible solution for this ? Kindly suggest

More Info: RPC call is successful and value is set to GridStore

Comment: Try to call forceLayout() after the data is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're missing a load handler that adds the rpc request results to the store.

```
loader.addLoadHandler(new LoadResultListStoreBinding<FilterPagingLoadConfig, Stock, PagingLoadResult<Stock>>(store));
```

The loading configuration would look something like this:

```
 RpcProxy<FilterPagingLoadConfig, PagingLoadResult<Stock>> dataProxy = new RpcProxy<FilterPagingLoadConfig, PagingLoadResult<Stock>>() {
  @Override
  public void load(FilterPagingLoadConfig loadConfig, AsyncCallback<PagingLoadResult<Stock>> callback) {
    getRpcStocks(loadConfig, callback);
  }
};

final PagingLoader<FilterPagingLoadConfig, PagingLoadResult<Stock>> loader = new PagingLoader<FilterPagingLoadConfig, PagingLoadResult<Stock>>(dataProxy);
loader.useLoadConfig(new FilterPagingLoadConfigBean());
loader.addLoadHandler(new LoadResultListStoreBinding<FilterPagingLoadConfig, Stock, PagingLoadResult<Stock>>(store));
```

Comment: Here is the test case source: https://gist.github.com/branflake2267/619ed6eb4e16b8b31b40